# Rank of permutations matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

Q.

Let $u=\left(u_{1}, u_{2}, \ldots, u_{n}\right)$ be a fixed non-zero vector in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ such that $u_{1}+u_{2}+\cdots+u_{n}=0$, and let $A$ be the $n ! \times n$ matrix whose rows are the $n$ ! permutations of $u$. Show that $\operatorname{rank}(A)=n-1$.

My approach:

Here $U=(u_1,..., u_n) $ and $A$  be the permutation matrix whose rows are the n! Permutations of $U$.

Here, $U=\left(u_{1}, u_{1}, \ldots . u_{n}\right)$.

$\pi:\left{u_{1}, \ldots, u_{n}\right} \rightarrow\left{u_{1}, \ldots u_{n}\right} .

$π$: $\left(\begin{array}{lll}u_{1} & u_{2} & u_{n} \\ u_{2} & u_{3} & u_{1}\end{array}\right)$

$A=\left(\begin{array}{c}e_{π_{1}} \\ e_{π_{2}} \\ \vdots \\ e_{π_{n}}\end{array}\right)$
$=\left(\begin{array}{c}e_{2} \\ e_{3} \\ \vdots \\ e_{1}\end{array}\right)$
$=\left(\begin{array}{lllllll}0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & \cdots & \cdots \\ \vdots & & & & & \cdots & \\ 1 & 0 & \cdots & & & \cdots & \end{array}\right)_{n ! \times n .}$

Here how can i use that $u_1+...+u_n=0$ and how can i show that rank of $A$ is $(n-1) $ ?

Comment: @ChristopheLeuridan I think that your comment relates to the second part of the question right ? In the first one I think $A$ is $n!\times n$, the second part is unrelated to the first one.

Comment: @ P. Quinton Yes, I answered too quickly. I deleted this comment. I give a complete answer below

Comment: Why don't you first work out what happens with $(u_1,u_2)=(1,-1)$ and $(u_1,u_2,u_3)=(1,0,-1)$. That would show some actual effort.

Comment: if $\text{rank}\big(A\big)\lt n-1$ that would imply the existence of at least 3 non-trivial $G$-invariant subspaces for the standard matrix representation of $S_n$ -- i.e. $\geq 3$ irreducibles.  OP's question seems to be ex 10.6.5 (which calls on ex 4.M.1) from Artin's *Algebra* 2nd edition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rows belong to hyperplane with equation $x_1+\cdots+x_n=0$, so the rank of $A$ is at most $n-1$.

Since $u$ is not null but $u_1+\cdots+u_n=0$, so $u$ has two different coordinates, $u_i \ne u_j$. By considering the differences of the two vectors $u \circ \pi^{-1}$ and $u \circ \pi^{-1} \circ \tau^{-1}$, where $\pi$ is any permutation sending $(i,j)$ on $(k,k+1)$ and $\tau$ the transposition exchanging $k$ and $k+1$, you check that each vector $e_{k+1}-e_k, 1 \le k \le n-1$ (where $(e_1,\ldots,e_n)$ denotes the canonical basis) is spanned by the rows of the matrix $A$, so the rank of $A$ is at least $n-1$.

We are done.

Below is an attempt to extract an $n \times n$ matrix with rank $n-1$.  partial answer. The matrix $A$ is $n! \times n$. The sum of the $n$ columns is null, so the rank is at most $n-1$.

Consider the circulant array
$$B = \left( \begin{array}{cccc} 
u_1 & u_n & \cdots & u_2 \\
u_2 & u_1 & \ddots & u_3 \\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots \\
u_n & u_{n-1} & \cdots & u_1
\end{array} \right).$$
This array is $u_1I + u_2C + \cdots + u_nC^{n-1}$, where $C$ is a permutation matrix
$$C = \left( \begin{array}{ccccc} 
0 & \cdots & \cdots & 0 & 1 \\
1 & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots  & 0 \\
0 & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & \cdots & 0 & 1 & 0
\end{array} \right).$$

Since the eigenvalues of $C$ are the $n$-th roots of unity, the eigenvalues of $B$ are $u_1 + u_2\zeta + \cdots + u_n\zeta^{n-1}$ where $\zeta$ ranges over the $n$-th roots of unity. When $\zeta=1$, you get the eigenvalue $0$. It suffices to check that the other eigenvalues are not $0$.

This may be false for particular choice of $(u_1,\ldots,u_n)$ but my impression is that some permutation $(u_\pi(1),\ldots,u_\pi(n))$ will work since $u_1,\ldots,u_n$ are not all the same.

Comment: I would be happy with the first seven lines (on my screen). I don't think looking for $n$ particular permutations adds much to the efficient solution :-)

Comment: Order it so that $u_1$ is the biggest and $u_n$ the smallest (it has to be negative since they sum to $0$ and it isn't zero-vector). So when you leave out the last row and column, Gerskorin circle theorem says zero isn't an eigenvalue of that matrix. By wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix#Other_properties (the last point) that matrix's characteristic polynomial is $\frac{1}{n}p'(x)$ where $p$ is the char of the orig matrix. So $0$ is a simple root of $p$.

Comment: I'm actually not sure if Gersgorin will work, since you have to put absolute values in there.