# Choose values so that the set $A=\left\{ \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{\sigma(i)}v_i : \sigma\in S_n \right\}$has rank $m$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, contest-math

I am trying to solve the following problem:

> Let $\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$ a basis of a real vector space $V$. Find all $m\in[0,n]\cap\mathbb{Z}$ for which there exist $a_1,\ldots,a_n\in\mathbb{R}$ such that the set $$A=\left\{ \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{\sigma(i)}v_i : \sigma\in S_n \right\}$$ has rank $m$.

For $m=0$, we know that it is possible to choose $a_i=0$ for all $i\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$ so that $A$ has rank $0$.

On the other hand, if we pick $a_i=1$ for all $i\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$, then the only vector in $A$ will be $v_1+\dots+v_n\neq 0$, so the rank of $A$ will be $m=1$.

In the case of $m=n$, we can choose $a_1=1$ and $a_i=0$ for all $i\in\{2,\ldots,n\}$ so that $\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\} \subseteq A$ and the rank of $A$ is $m=n$.

I guess that it is not possible to prove the existence of the $a_i$'s for the other values of $m$, but I am not sure.

Comment: If you re-write this as $\mathbf B:=\bigg[\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}  v_1 &  v_2 &\cdots &  v_{n}\end{array}\bigg]$ then you are asking about $\text{rank}\big(\mathbf BA\big) = \text{rank}\big(A\big)$  where $A$ is a $n\times n!$ matrix containing all possible permutations of some vector $\mathbf u$ that you choose.  Your problem then is nearly a duplicate of a question from earlier this week https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4437265/rank-of-permutations-matrix -- in particular this address that $n-1$ case and eliminates all other remaining possibilities except perhaps $n-2$

Comment: @user8675309 why might the argument of that post allow the possibility of $n-2$?

Comment: I had triangle inequality on my mind when I wrote that comment.  I suppose it is fairly straightforward to verify the case of $A'=A + \beta J$ where (up to transposition) $A$ is a matrix contemplated in that post and adding the ones vector to each row gives $\text{rank}\big(A'\big) = n$